# How to get uploaded file size in Slim Framework?

Tags: slim, slim-3

I'm unable to get the uploaded file size in slim framework. I wanted to do some validation on size. Here is my small code.

```
public function uploadFile(Request $request, Response $response){
 $files = $request->getUploadedFiles();
}
```

**$file['image']** is my file object.

Answer (score 3):

I got it actually this was very easy.

```
$files['image']->getSize()
```